# Fill table with result from Oracle SQL query in PHP (adobe.inc.php included)

Tags: php, sql, oracle, fill

I'm trying to fill a table with the result from a certain SQL query, but I dont know why it doesnt work, heres my code:

```
<?

if(!ceklogin()){
header("Location:index.php");
}
?><?

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>MSystem</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <LINK href="gaya.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<?
    //$cfgProgDir = 'phpSecurePages/phpSecurePages/';
    //include($cfgProgDir . "secure.php");
    include_once("top4.htm");
    include_once("conn.php");
    $datenow = getdate();
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendarDateInput.js">

</script>

<body class="bg">

<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td><p align="center"><strong><font color="#000000" size="2">TITLE</font></strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p align="center"><strong><font color="#000000" size="3"> SMALL TITLE</font></strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p align="center"><strong><font color="#000000" size="2">Date: <? echo $v_date ?></font></strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p align=center><strong><font color=#000000 size=2>SMALLER TITLE</font></strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="img/batas.jpg" width="750" height="1" ></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>
<table class=table width="750" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor=black bgcolor="#DDDDDD" BORDER-COLLAPSE"collapse">

////////// THIS IS THE TABLE

<tr>
    <td bgcolor=#444444 align=center><font color=white>Date</font></td>
    <td bgcolor=#444444 align=center><font color=white>Type</font></td>
    <td bgcolor=#444444 align=center><font color=white>Sender</font></td>
    <td bgcolor=#444444 align=center><font color=white>Description</font></td>
    <td bgcolor=#444444 align=center><font color=white>Credit</font></td>
    <td bgcolor=#444444 align=center><font color=white>Quantity</font></td>
    <td bgcolor=#444444 align=center><font color=white>Price</font></td>
</tr>

<?
    $blnto = substr($v_date,3,3);
    switch($blnto)
    {
        case 'JAN': {$blntov = '01'; break;}
        case 'FEB': {$blntov = '02'; break;}
        case 'MAR': {$blntov = '03'; break;}
        case 'APR': {$blntov = '04'; break;}
        case 'MAY': {$blntov = '05'; break;}
        case 'JUN': {$blntov = '06'; break;}
        case 'JUL': {$blntov = '07'; break;}
        case 'AUG': {$blntov = '08'; break;}
        case 'SEP': {$blntov = '09'; break;}
        case 'OCT': {$blntov = '10'; break;}
        case 'NOV': {$blntov = '11'; break;}
        case 'DEC': {$blntov = '12'; break;}
    }
    $tglto = substr($v_date,0,2);
    $thnto = substr($v_date,7,4);

////////////    HERES THE QUERY

    $MyQuery = "
select date, type, sender, description, credit, quantity, change 
from harjunadip.REPORTENABLEREGAE 
WHERE date = '".$thnto."-".$blntov."-".$tglto."' 
//test with: WHERE date = '2015-10-05'
order by description
";
    //echo $MyQuery;

    $curs=ora_open($conn);
    ora_parse($curs,$MyQuery, 0);
    ora_exec($curs);

    $i=1;

    $tot_qty_p = 0;
    $tot_sal_p = 0;
    $tot_qty_v = 0;
    $tot_sal_v = 0;

    while(ora_fetch($curs) == 1) // WHILE THERE IS A ROW
    {
        $bgcolor = "";
        if ($i % 2 != 1) $bgcolor = "bgcolor=#FFFFCC";

///////// THIS IS THE SUPPOSED TABLE CONTENTS

        $content = "
        <tr ".$bgcolor.">
            <td align=\"center\">".ora_getcolumn($curs,0)."</td>
            <td align=\"right\">".ora_getcolumn($curs,1)."</td>
            <td align=\"right\">".ora_getcolumn($curs,2)."</td>
            <td align=\"right\">".ora_getcolumn($curs,3)."</td>
            <td align=\"right\">".number_format(ora_getcolumn($curs,4))."</td>
            <td align=\"right\">".number_format(ora_getcolumn($curs,5))."</td>
            <td align=\"right\">".number_format(ora_getcolumn($curs,6),2,'.',',')."</td>
        </tr>
        ";   

        $tot_qty = $tot_qty + ora_getcolumn($curs,5);
        $tot_price = $tot_price + ora_getcolumn($curs,6);;
        echo $content;
        $i++;
    }
    ora_close($curs);
?>
        <tr bgcolor="#444444">
            <td align="right" colspan="5"><font color="#FFFFFF">Total :</font></td>
            <td align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"><? echo number_format($tot_qty) ?></font></td>
            <td align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"><? echo number_format($tot_price,2,'.',',') ?></font></td>
        </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Things to consider:

1. The query works, Ive tried the query by replacing '".$thnto."-".$blntov."-".$tglto."' with '2015-10-05' and it gives me the result.
2. The table appears but only the headers (DATE, TYPE, SENDER, etc)
3. The connection to the database also works, so its not a connection problem
4. I'm using adobe.inc.php with oci8 connection if that matters

I just cant seem to put the result on the said table. Ive tried echoing some random stuff like this:

```
select date, type, sender, description, credit, quantity, change 
from harjunadip.REPORTENABLEREGAE 
WHERE date = '".$thnto."-".$blntov."-".$tglto."' 
//test with: WHERE date = '2015-10-05'
order by description
";
    echo 'test1';

    $curs=ora_open($conn);
    ora_parse($curs,$MyQuery, 0);
    echo 'test2';
    ora_exec($curs);

    echo 'test3';
    $i=1;

    $tot_qty_p = 0;
    $tot_sal_p = 0;
    $tot_qty_v = 0;
    $tot_sal_v = 0;

    while(ora_fetch($curs) == 1) // WHILE THERE IS A ROW
    echo 'test4';
    {
        $bgcolor = "";
        if ($i % 2 != 1) $bgcolor = "bgcolor=#FFFFCC";
```

But only the 'test1' appeared, the others didnt.

Kindly help please, I'm lost, thanks in advance.

Comment: is $conn defined?

just add error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

on the top of the file and see the error.

Comment: $conn is defined, $conn is used to make the connection to the database. I've put the line add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); on the top, but I cant find the error message

Comment: Oh wait nevermind, I can see the error, thank you very much

Comment: Okay so now I know that my ora_open, ora_fetch, ora_anything command is outdated and I replaced it with $curs=$conn->Execute($MyQuery); and to call the fields I use: .$curs->fields[QUANTITY]. But now I encounter a new problem. The error says: Notice: Use of undefined constant QUANTITY- assumed 'QUANTITY' in /apps/hss/jkins/new_rc_dayReport.php on line 118. Maybe the code doesnt recognize my query? But the query works, Ive checked it. What seems to be the problem? @NIRANJANS.